# Kendo existing table search

Tags: kendo-ui

I am initialize a Grid from an existing table with is working fine but the search toolbar is missing? Is there something I am doing wrong to search from an existing table?

dojo
https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevittnccn/OpEluMeF

Comment: No but something about your table is messing kendo up. If I remove all but one thead element and lose the tr from within the thead then the search box appears.

Comment: did it search the result once you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add search fields:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
       sortable: true,
       toolbar: ["search"],
       search: {
         fields: ['model', 'year', 'category', 'airconditioner']
       },
    });
});
```

Example: [Search toolbar](https://dojo.telerik.com/UTuteyul)